# Java intent send me blank page

Tags: java, android, android-intent

to create an application for a restaurant as an internship, i made an intent to be sent to the command page. however the intent send me a blank page. here is how the code is made:

```
mButtonCommande.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  

  @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        OpenCommandeActivity();

    }


    });

}
private void OpenCommandeActivity() {
    Intent connect = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CommandeActivity.class);
    startActivity(connect);
}
```

intitially, the page is black, so if anyone could help me, thank you in advance.

here is the XML fro the starting page:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="*">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonAccessCommande"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/commandAccessButton"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/orange"
                android:onClick="openCommandeActivity"
                tools:ignore="OnClick" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and here is the Java for the second page:

```
package com.example.tacoskingapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterViewAnimator;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class CommandeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Button mButtonFinalCommande;
    private EditText mNomClient;
    private EditText mAdresseClient;
    private Spinner mListProduit;
    private ArrayList<String>ListProducts;// liste d'items ayant pour titre

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_commaande);
        mButtonFinalCommande=findViewById(R.id.button2);
       // mListProduit=findViewById(R.id.spinner_produit);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>AdapterProduct = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.product_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        AdapterProduct.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mListProduit.setAdapter(AdapterProduct);// je connect ici mon spinner et mon adapteur
        mListProduit.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        Intent connect = getIntent();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
    String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to be able to help you. Please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update the question to have enough details so someone else could run it and see the same behavior you are describing.

Comment: well. here is the page from an XML point of view

Comment: This is still not a complete example - but the issue is probably in your setup of `CommandeActivity` rather than anything to do with the intent. Maybe add a `TextView` at the top of the activity with a title so you know you're on the right page, then you can work on figuring out how to show a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to go to Commande Activity on click button, use this.

```
mButtonCommande.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        OpenCommandeActivity();
    }
}

private void OpenCommandeActivity() {
    Intent connect = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CommandeActivity.class);
    startActivity(connect);
}
```

But if you want to add another function on the way going to Commande Activity, make sure to put the code of the function before the `OpenCommandeActivity()`, like this one.

```
mButtonCommande.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        OpenCommandeActivity();
    }
}

private void OpenCommandeActivity() {
    Intent connect = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CommandeActivity.class);
    startActivity(connect);
}
```

And don't forget to specify it in the AndroidManifest.xml, as below.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true" />
<activity
    android:name=".CommandeActivity"
    android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: now ir makes my application crash

Comment: If you aren't providing the full codes, it's going to be difficult for getting help. If you can't share it, I suggest look at the error code in the Logcat.

Comment: Provide the layout for CommandeActivity.

Comment: thx i reloved it soon after. sorry for my miperfect english, i'm just not a native speaker

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
setContentView(r.layout.activity_commande)
```